# wp_login_form hidden redirect value

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom login template for my wordpress and used wp_login_forms with custom arguments. In my arguments i commented out redirect so it wont redirect to any page. So now i get the default redirect which the request URI samplewebsite.com/login.
$args = array (
//'redirect' => home_url(),
)
Just want to ask if its possible to remove the `<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://samplewebsite.com/login" \>` that shows on the form when using wp_login_form because i have a plugin that will process the redirection after logging in and they say that we should get rid of any redirect from the form.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is too broad and suggests you haven't actually tried doing it. It is likely going to attract downvotes. Please investigate the problem, find the relevant code in php, try commenting it out, consult the plugin documentation, troubleshoot it inside out. When you hit an issue, share it here, along with detailed explanation. In the meanwhile, please have a read of [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. Will change my question to make it look better.